# Scoping SCSS @font-face variables for use with Font Face Observer

Tags: fonts, sass, font-face, multilingual, scoping

So I maintain a site where we use Font Face Observer: https://fontfaceobserver.com — we currently define fonts like this:

```
$serif: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
$serifFontface: 'Chronicle Display', $serif;

%serif {
  font-family: $serif;
  .fonts-loaded&{
    font-family: $serifFontface;
  }
}
```

We are now in the process of modifying the codebase for use as a multilingual site, where there will always be **both** Roman and Japanese Kanji characters on a page.

We have a body class `.isJa` and I tried scoping like this, but the Kanji fontface appears in the stack even without the class being present on the body:

```
$serif: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;

.isJa{
  $serif: 'hiragino kaku gothic pro', Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

$serifFontface: 'Chronicle Display', $serif;

%serif {
  font-family: $serif;
  .fonts-loaded &{
    font-family: $serifFontface;
  }
}
```

How / is it possible to achieve the desired outcome? i.e. the hiragino font is only declared when `.isJa` is present, but is declared initially and also when Font Face Observer applies the `.fonts-loaded` class. I should probably add that we are limited to Sass v3.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got bitten by @extend. Extended rules are generated only once - in the exact moment when you declare the %placeholder. Changing variables later won't affect them. This is (one of reasons) why using @extend in general is discouraged.

What you should do is to use a mixin that has a default parameter set to your initial variable value.

Code:

```
$serifFontface: 'Chronicle Display';

@mixin fontFallback($fallback: (Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif)) {
  font-family: $fallback;
  &.fonts-loaded {
    font-family: $serifFontface, $fallback;
  }
}

body {
  @include fontFallback;
}

.isJa {
  $japaneseFallback: 'hiragino kaku gothic pro', Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  @include fontFallback($japaneseFallback);
}
```

Output:

```
body {
  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
body.fonts-loaded {
  font-family: "Chronicle Display", Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.isJa {
  font-family: "hiragino kaku gothic pro", Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
.isJa.fonts-loaded {
  font-family: "Chronicle Display", "hiragino kaku gothic pro", Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

Read more about mixins and extends [here](https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/) and [here](https://sass-guidelin.es/#extend).

Comment: "I see!" said the blind man. Excellent. Thank you also for the references

Comment: "The way gzip works means that we get better savings even when our uncompresssed files are substantially larger." — [Fascinating!](https://csswizardry.com/2016/02/mixins-better-for-performance/) Thanks again

Comment: Using `@extend` "in general is discouraged"? By who, and why?

Comment: @vtamm, thanks for asking : ). There is a number of webdevs who are bespoken against `@extend`, as it has almost no upsides over `@mixin`. I urge you to do a web search for "extend is bad practice scss" - not because I'm being condescending, but because SO isn't really a good place for this discussion. You'll find a number of blog posts that explain reasons for avoiding `@extend`, and how little it offers over `@mixin`, in concise way.

Comment: @Senthe thanks for the response! I don't doubt that it's true, just felt that the statement warranted some more weight behind it. :)